# reduce() function in Typescript with instantiate empty object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to convert my Javascript function to a Typescript version of it but I'm not able to get rid of the read underlined code `acc[curr.name]` (in VSCode). Which says when hovering over it:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.

I'm counting occurrences by key name.

Where should I define the type and why is an empty object or object with number not working.
I'm not sure how to solve it as I tried multiple things, like for example:

`data.reduce<{}>()`
and `data.reduce<{property: number}>()`

**Code:**

```
const data = [
  { name: "name1", },
  { name: "name1", },
  { name: "name1", },
  { name: "name1", },
  { name: "name2", },
  { name: "name2", },
  { name: "name2", },
  { name: "name1", },
];

// count data by key name
const resultData = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  return acc[curr.name] ? ++acc[curr.name] : (acc[curr.name] = 1), acc;
}, {});
```

**Result when running:**

```
const resultData = {
  name1: 4,
  name2: 3,
  name3: 1,
};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set a index signature like `data.reduce<{ [index: string]: number }>`

Ref: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures

```
const resultData = data.reduce<{ [index: string]: number }>((acc, curr) => {
  return acc[curr.name] ? ++acc[curr.name] : (acc[curr.name] = 1), acc;
}, {});
```

Or you can use `as` keyword with initial value.

```
const resultData = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  return acc[curr.name] ? ++acc[curr.name] : (acc[curr.name] = 1), acc;
}, {} as { [index: string]: number });
```

Comment: Great, thank you for your answer! Would you be so kind and add also a link to the documentation. Thanks.

Comment: @BenjaminK I've updated the post.